# No files in recycle bin?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, data-recovery, file-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best undelete tool for NTFS/FAT?](https://superuser.com/questions/6810/best-undelete-tool-for-ntfs-fat)

I have a huge problem and im wondering if anyone might be able to help me with it.

I have a mounted drive (`Z:`) but its actually a virtual drive that leads to `C:\work\`.

Well, i have accidently delete some stuff from it and its not in the recycle bin. Is there ANY way to get it back? Please please tell me there is!

Eagerly awaiting a response! Ian

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times before. Links to all of these questions, and their answers, are in the sidebar to the right of the screen. We cannot begin to help you until you tell us what OS and what filesystem you are using. Once you know what those are, please search for the appropriate question.

Comment: I think he is using windows...  Not sure.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry, im using win7 (x64), im not sure what my file system is (how do i check). This seems to be exactly the same quesiton, but its for win xp, so doesnt seem to apply, ie, i dont have a "Z:\recycler", has this functionality changed in windows7 do you know? (http://superuser.com/questions/317378/where-are-files-in-the-recycle-bin-stored-in-respect-of-partitions)

Comment: By "virtual drive", do you mean a mapped drive to the shared "C:\work" folder? If so, there is no recycle bin for files deleted over a network share.

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/search?q=ntfs+data+recovery) is a list of all the relevant questions.

Comment: Time to hunt down those data recovery programs. . .