# Are some files that show up in the Windows Recycle Bin of a fully formatted secondary drive linked to another drive or physically present?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, file-recovery, wipe

I have a primary (boot) SSD and a secondary HDD (via a SATA-to-USB adapter) connected to my computer. My goal is to sell the secondary HDD without exposing any previous data that was stored on it. I just performed a `format D: /P:0` via an admin cmd.exe instance on the drive. Afterwards, I noticed that Windows created an invisible `System Volume Information` folder on the drive. I then scanned the drive for recoverable files (with Recuva) and only found 24 system files. However, afterwards I noticed another invisible folder created at the root: `Recycle Bin`. After clicking on it, and then another `Recycle Bin` subfolder, I found a large number of personal files. I subsequently 'emptied' all these files, without trying to discern the origin (SSD or HDD). My guess is that this folder simply links all system recycle bins into one 'view,' as I performed a subfolder-scan with Recuva aferwards, and it only displayed `desktop.ini` (while 'emptied' files from the Recycle Bin are presumably recoverable).

Are some files that show up in the Windows Recycle Bin of a fully formatted secondary drive linked or physically present?

Comment: [*Where are files in the Recycle Bin stored, in respect of partitions?*](https://superuser.com/q/317378/432690) – Almost a duplicate: XP there, Win10 here.

Comment: Note you wouldn't experience this issue related to Recycle Bin if you used a better tool. As far as I know `format` creates a filesystem. This was *not* your goal. Filling with zeros is just an extra (optional) effect of `format`. I'm into Linux, so I'll give you mostly Linux examples of better tools: `shred`, `dd if=/dev/zero`, [ATA Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase). My point is: erasing the drive *without* creating any filesystem would prevent Windows from creating any structures.

Comment: Why are you using `format D: /P:0` instead of `format D: /P:1`?

Comment: RockPaperLizard I think /P:x refers to *additional* passes. One pass is always done by default, unless the quick format flag is set